# The density of an aqueous solution

Tags: aqueous-solution, solutions

Could the density of an aqueous solution be less than 1g/ml ? For an example, can 0.98g/ml be taken as a density for an aqueous sulphuric acid solution ?

Comment: Yes. With the exception of negative quantities or ones where the reaction quotient exceeds the solubility product, anything is fair game.

Comment: Sol. of H2SO4 tend to be denser then water.

Answer (score 2):

Answer to your question, "could the density of an aqueous solution be less than $\pu{1g/mL}$," is yes. See following examples:

The density of the commercially available 28% ammonia solution ($\ce{NH3}$ 1n $\ce{H2O}$) is listed as $\pu{0.9 g/mL}$ at 25 °C ([Sigma-Aldrich Catalog](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/sigald/338818?lang=en&region=US)).

*MERCK Tabellen für das Labor* has listed the density of 35% ammonia solution ($\pu{18 mol/L}$ concentration) as $\pu{0.88 g/mL}$ at 20 °C ([Steffen's Chemistry Pages](https://wissen.science-and-fun.de/chemistry/chemistry/concentration-of-commercially-available-acids-and-bases/))

As obvious, the densities of various aqueous ethanol solutions are also equal to less than unity since the density of absolute ethanol is $\pu{0.789 g/mL}$ at 20 °C ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethanol)). By a quick google search, I found the densities of various aqueous ethanol solutions listed in *MERCK Tabellen für das Labor*  in [Steffen's Chemistry Pages](https://wissen.science-and-fun.de/chemistry/chemistry/density-tables/ethanol-water-mixtures/), which is pretty interesting.